# How to trim <ul> and <li> tag, but the value of <li> will be the remain same?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created an ajax method to search for User Lists.
But the ajax function returning me such as :

```
 <ul><li>User Name</li></ul>
```

I want to trim `<ul></ul>` and `<li></li>` tag in main page to use the exact value.

Like :

Before :

```
<ul><li>User Name</li></ul>
```

After :

> User Name

The ajax result will store in :

```
<div class="input-group" id="userList"></div>
```

I have done already some javascript method to do so

## Ajax function :

```
< script >
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#run').keyup(function() {
        var query = $(this).val();
        if (query != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "userSearch.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    query: query
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#userList').fadeIn();
                    $('#userList').html(data);
                    paymentStatus(data);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#userList').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
        $('#run').val($(this).text());
        $('#userList').fadeOut();
    });
    }); <
/script>
```

## userSearch.php File Code :

```
<?php
require_once '../../config/config.php';
if(isset($_POST['query']))
{
    $output = '';
    $query = "SELECT Name, Id FROM ucoe_users WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST['query']."%' AND RoleId = 3";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $output = '<ul>';
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0 )
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $output .= "<li>".$row['Name']."</li>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output .= '<li>User Not Found</li>';
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: these are html tags. What do you mean by trimming tags?

Comment: i want to discard these ul and li tags but the value will be the same

Comment: Why would you add stuff in the first place, only to then trim it later? Why not modify your PHP script to not output these tags in the first place …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(html).text()` to get text value from your html

```
           success: function(data) {
                $('#userList').fadeIn();
                $('#userList').html($(data).text());
                paymentStatus(data);
            }
```

```js
var html = '<ul><li>User Name</li></ul>';

console.log($(html).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery as following ,

```
    var arrOfValues = [];
    $('ul li').each(function(i)
    {
       arrOfValues.push($(this).text()); //every value of ul li will be push in arrOfvalues.

    });
$('#userList').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was a DOM element then it would be straight forward just get innerText

for eg :

```
<ol>
<li>User Name</li>
</ol>

<script>
var olDom = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");
console.log(olDom[0].innerText)
</script>
```

But in your case you are getting HTML as a response of Ajax, so first we need to create a wrapper div to hold your response in a form of DOM and then we will call innerText.

```
<script>
var wrapperDiv = document.createElement('div');
wrapperDiv.innerHTML = data;
$('#userList').html(wrapper.innerText);
</script>
```